# Какая тут ошибка?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<text javascript="">
<script>
    var val = $("input[name=name_of_input]").val();
    if (val == 1) document.location.href = '65.html';
    else if (val == 2) document.location.href = '43.html';
    else alert("Данный код в баззе не храниться!");
</script>
</html>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: нету такого теша <text javascript="">.

Comment: убери он вовсе не нужен

Comment: подключи jquery библиотеку

Comment: напишите полностью как надо начиная с <html> и заканчивая </html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никто достоверно не знает, что вы там хотели получить на выходе, но мой хрустальный шар подсказывает, что вы хотите по значению текстового поля открывать другую страницу или обругать пользователя.

Предположим, что вы хотите, чтобы это происходило по нажатию клавиши Enter после ввода значения в поле:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script lang="javascript">
    function onKeyPress(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        val = $("input[name=name_of_input]").val();
        if (val == 1) document.location.href = '65.html';
        else if (val == 2) document.location.href = '43.html';
        else alert("Данный код в базе не хранится!");
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" name="name_of_input" onKeyPress="onKeyPress(event)"/>
</body>
</html>
```

---

UPD1. Вариант с кнопкой.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script lang="javascript">
    function onClick() {
        val = $("input[name=name_of_input]").val();
        if (val == 1) document.location.href = '65.html';
        else if (val == 2) document.location.href = '43.html';
        else alert("Данный код в базе не хранится!");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" name="name_of_input" />
  <input type="button" value="Проверить" onClick="onClick()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Не стесняйтесь экспериментировать, править код и смотреть, что получится.

Comment: А как сделать что бы еще и кнопка с текстом "проверить" была?

Comment: Обновил ответ.